# pylint allow variable names that start / end with X_ / _X

Tags: python, regex, lint, pylint

I am getting a pylint error, specifically C0103.

How can I allow any variable names that start with X_ (for example), or end with _X.

For example, I want lint to ignore names like train_X or y_test etc

Answer (score 2):

Pylint *does* allow [custom variable names](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/options.html#custom-regular-expressions) via regular expressions, so you could use the following command to define your own pattern rule:

```
pylint --variable-rgx='(?:X_)?[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*(?:_X)?' example.py
```

Comment: how can I implement this in .pylintrc? I put it in [MASTER] good_names_rgxs= '(?:X_)?[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*(?:_X)?' but still getting the same message